# Is there a reuse of virtual memory addresses in linux?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual, space, reusability

I thought a little about virtual memory management, and came to the result that there can be two types of memory fragmentation. The first happens on the physical memory side where pages can not be freed because there are some bytes of it used. Mostly the last bytes will be freed sooner or later and then the physical memory page will become free again and is unmapped.

But what happens to the pointer (virtual address) returned by malloc. Let's assume a 32-bit system. The program "randomly" allocates and frees memory but there is never used more than some MByte. Let's assume further that the program will never free the memory in the order it is allocated. So the "top of heap" pointer can never be decreased as the free will never occur at the end of the heap. I assume that malloc has to map the memory always to the end of the heap memory space. This means the pointer value will increase with every call.

Earlier or later the returned pointer will reach the highest possible address (e.g. `0xffffffff`) and it becomes impossible to further add memory while the system has enough free pages available as most pages have been freed. It is just a matter of the highest possible pointer value.

To solve this an algorithm would be needed that maintains unmapped address spaces and let them grow as more memory is beeing freed at the beginning or the end of the space. Is there an algorithm like this implemented by malloc?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that malloc has to map the memory always to the end of the heap memory space.

This assumption is actually incorrect. Some implementations may keep multiple pools that different sizes of blocks are allocated from. (For instance, one common approach is a [slab allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation), which keeps a separate pool for each size of block that the allocator will return.)

In any case, **yes** — all meaningful implementations of `malloc()` will track memory that has been freed and will reuse it when possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had a short look at the slab allocator. This seems to be more related to memory page management used inside kernel. My question is related to the user space and the fact that whenever memory is allocated it needs to get an address in address space of the calling process's heap. What happens to this address space when it is limited as given in a 32-bit system.

It is clear that the system does not loose the memory at all. What I mean is that there is no address space left to get an address where the memory can be mapped while all memory at lower addresses has been freed and unmapped already.